# How to get top 5 products bought from my database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display the top 5 products bought from my database,

Top 5 Products

```
banana
apple
orange
mango 
egg
```

I have a table that displays all and if the row repeats by more than lets say 2 it would be a top product. how will i do it?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: I think you will need to add more information before people can help you answer this question. To start, what is the structure of your table? (`show create table products;`).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name FROM products GROUP BY name ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC LIMIT 5;
```

eventually:

```
SELECT name FROM products GROUP BY name HAVING count(name) > 2 ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC LIMIT 5;
```